# Need to fix program in Java

Tags: java

I want user to input text while it is not equal to "start".When it is equal to "start" I want to show "Bravo".In my code when I enter "start" it just continue to ask to input a text.What is missing in my code to process the operation i described.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String komanda = "a";
    do { 
        System.out.println("Unesi komandu ");
        komanda = input.nextLine();
    }
    while(komanda != "start");
    System.out.println("Bravo");
  }
}
```

Comment: if I only see one more "java strings compare" question,I will throw my cat out of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the equals method to compare strings in java:

```
while (!komanda.equals("start"));
```

or even better

```
while (!"start".equals(komanda));
```

this does not crash if `komanda` is `null`

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more information.

Comment: +1 for recommending literal on left hand side.

Comment: @Adam `komanda` cannot possibly be `null` and the Yoda condition doesn't read as naturally.

Comment: Sometimes a certain String not being null can be an important condition for the program to work, so it is not necessarily good to avoid the NullPointerException. Just depends of the context.

Comment: Always use LHS literal as static analysis tools aren't smart enough to work out the context. It reads just as naturally for most people ;) Also never trust the lines before your condition, codes changes, just because it can't yield null today might not be true tomorrow after someone else edits it...

Answer (score 0):

do it this way

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String komanda = "a";
        do { 
            System.out.println("Unesi komandu ");
            komanda = input.nextLine();
        }
        while(!"start".equals(komanda));
        System.out.println("Bravo");
```